# Input element fill up remaining width

Tags: css

There are already many questions raised about CSS & remaining width. After reading them I still have a problem I cannot fix. When trying to let an input element use up the remaining width it is always 4px wider than its containing `div`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <div style='float:left; margin-right:10px;'>Hello:</div>
        <div style='overflow:hidden'><input style='width:100%'/></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The `input` element is always 4 pixels too wide to show its right border. If I set the `margin-left` of the input to `-4px` it becomes visible but then the left border is not shown.

Tested this with Chrome.

Comment: Can we see your CSS too?

Comment: The code above is complete. In this simplified example I used the `style` attribute iso a separate CSS file. You can just paste it in jsfiddle.

Comment: But there's not much in the CSS to suggest you have a "fill remainng space" solution in place?

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks Look at `float: left;` along with `overflow: hidden;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add `box-sizing: border-box;` to your `input` to avoid the overflow. What it does basically is that the borders and padding will be taken into consideration when setting `width: 100%`. Note that you'd have to include several vendor-prefixed for different browsers:

```
.myinput {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid orange; /*just to make border more clear*/
    width: 100%;
}
```

Little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/3WtXh/).